# returning opencv processed frame to tkinter GUI

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a program that processes a video using multiple techniques based on selection and that has GUI. one of the methods is called background subtraction that process video frame by frame. and I have show frame method that sends the frame to GUI after getting the frame from method whichone which calls the techniques to start based on selection of user . the problem is that, if i returned the processed frame using return it will stop the loop processing video and stop the function.

```
def DayBackgroundSubtraction():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture ('dataset/video92.mp4')
        while cap.isOpened():
            # do Processing
            return frame
def show_frame():
    lmain = Label(bottomFrame)
    lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)
    (ret, frame) = vid_capture.read()
    # receive frame from selected techniques
    frame = whichOne()
    if ret == True:
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = _image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, show_frame)
    else:
        lmain.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a recursive function that will never end when you call `lmain.after(10, show_frame)`. This is bad, can you see how the `show_frame` function will never exit? I'm pretty sure this also causes the weird behavior you experience. Instead you should separate the function call from the function itself.

```
    import cv2
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    # get camera 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('dataset/video92.mp4')

    def updateGUI(img):
        # convert to PIL
        img_arr = Image.fromarray(img)
        img_pi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_arr)
        lmain.configure(image=img_pi)

    # loop forever while camera is open
    while cap.isOpened():
            # Get a frame from the video source
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                    # process frame
                    processed_frame = image_processing_function(frame)
                    # get a new processed frame 
                    updateGUI(processed_frame)
                    # wait 10 ms - change value to change playback speed
            cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Disclaimer: untested code

Comment: thanks for the answer.the full question is at    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820934/integrating-opencv-processed-video-with-tkinter    . can you take a look

Comment: i tried the code but now the problem is reversed. earlier the detection doesn't work but the video would play but now the detection works in background and prints the command but the video doesn't play on the GUI

Comment: If you disable the detection, does it show in the GUI?